# How to add AliasNbPages to MultiCell

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

To display how many pages are in this pdf you can actually use

```
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{customNb}');
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{customNb}', 0, 0, 'C');
```

This should print something like e.g.

> Page 1/5

What if i'm using a MultiCell, how can I use AliasNbPages there ?

```
$pdf->MultiCell(34, 5, 'Page '.$pdf->PageNo() . '/{customNb}');
```

This returns

> Page 1/{customNb}

I tried to pass it like sample above, also as a part of a variable

```
$foo = 'Page '.$pdf->PageNo() . '/{customNb}';
$pdf->MultiCell(34, 5, $foo);
```

But this all is not working as expacted. Is there an other way to solve this ???

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I found a solution....

obviously there is a problem using custom name for pageiterator.

If I simply call

```
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
```

and than use

```
$pdf->MultiCell(34, 5, 'Page '.$pdf->PageNo() . '/{nb}');
```

everything works like expacted.